# Is there any simple SQL ORM for C#?

Tags: c#, sql, orm

I'm not looking for anything that will do any fancy queries, use state-of-the-art C# funny business to generate slick queries, automagically map classes to database tables, or anything that works off of loads of metadata that has to be configured by a developer. In fact, I want the ORM to be agnostic to the fact that I am using C#.

Instead, I want to be able to perform simple commands to perform basic SQL tasks, such as:

1. A class to handle a connection to a SQL Server and perform Dynamic TSQL statements.
2. A class to represent the Database, with the ability to create the database, drop the database, find, add, or drop tables, etc.
3. A class to represent tables in the database, add columns, drop columns, etc.

However, each of these would preferably be as simple providing strings to get at the table:

```
connection = new ConnectionToSQLServer(connectionString);
database = connection.FindDatabase("MyDatabase");
foreach(Table table in database.Tables())
{
     table.AddColumn("MyColumn", typeof(String), COLUMNS::NOT_NULL)
     ...
}
```

Is there anything remotely like this when dealing with SQL and C#? I'm not terribly worried about having a top performing apparatus.

Comment: ORMs don't normally handle DDL (ie. add/drop columns).

Comment: Fair enough, I'm assuming it would do things like CRUD operations on tables as well. I'm hoping to have a one-stop shop for all of the database operations from setting up a database to performing simple actions.

Comment: You really don't want #2 via ORM. Separately - maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have described is not an ORM. An ORM is an *object-relational mapper*. That is, it is *specifically designed* to map database tables and queries to objects in whatever language it's designed for. In addition, the other things you've mentioned (DDL stuff) is usually not part of an ORM (this is not a hard rule, since there are things like Entity Framework that can handle, to some extent, database schema upgrades).

If you are targeting SQL Server, you could look at [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) to handle database and server maintenance tasks using a managed API vs. T-SQL statements, but that's obviously specific to SQL Server and .NET languages.

With regard to #1 on your list, what is it you're looking for that isn't already served with the `DbConnection/DbCommand/DbDataReader/etc.` classes?

Comment: I'll look into those classes. I've been looking through google searches for those things, but I'm probably looking for the wrong terms. The results keep coming up with things like NHibernate or Entity Framework, both of which seem more complicated when it comes to configuration than I'm hoping to have.

Comment: Yeah, NHibernate and Entity Framework are both ORM's, so if you're looking to stay away from ORM functionality, then they're not your best bet ;) I don't really think there's much out there that's database-agnostic for DDL, since DLL isn't something that's usually part of a LOB application.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this. I have a DLL that does all simple SQL functions (insert, update, select, ...). It is not terribly difficult to write a method that represents a SQL function. My advice would be to use a string[] for column values and and a matching string[] for column headers. That can handle the `addColumn` function and other functions on that level. As for `ConnectiontoSQLServer`, `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` seem to pretty much handle that? You can pass the connection string into your `addColumn` method and just have two using statements:

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connection))
{                                                                                                                         
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insert, connect))
   {
```

As for `FindDatabase`, same thing? C# already has `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. All you need is strings anyway, it can't be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely take a look at SQL Data (http://sqldata.codeplex.com).  I think that you will find that it can handle all of your requirements without the bloat of typical ORMs.  It is true that it is not really standard practice to handle DDL operations, but it certainly can execute any command on the database.

(Disclosure:  I am the author of SQL Data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.net MVC and entity framework code first, which will generate the database and tables as you code and can handle CRUD coding for you as you may focus on the application as a whole.

see more about ASP.net MVC EF [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
and more about CRUD in code first [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application).